# Loading data to Remote SQL Server Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I need some suggestions about a problem in hand. I receive some report  containing some financial transactions in Excel files. The Excel data needs to be loaded to a SQLServer Database running  behind fire wall. The file is transmitted to a Windows machine which does not have access to the SQL Server over port 1433. 
So is there any other option to load the Excel content (we can convert it to XML if need be) other than web services.
Is it possible to use XMLBulk load under such circumstances?
In case web services is the only option what is the best practice for bulk loading data through web services.
Thanks for sparing you time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS in order to convert data of your excel file to SQL Server.

SSIS run on the server and must be access to your excel file from network.

In this method windows firewall not effect to your process.

Comment: SQL Server is running at a Data Center.  I am not allowed to write any   file on the  DB server or any other place the DB Server might have access to.

Comment: You must only create SSIS Project on your system and deploy your project on sql server and then create SQL Server job for execute your ssis package automatically.